# Difficulties injecting shellcode with buffer overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

For an assignment I am doing, I must inject shellcode to execute execve(/bin/bash) into the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void return_input(void)
{
    char array[30];
    gets(array);
    printf(array);
}

main()
{
    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

I disassembled return_input and found that the buffer is 38 bytes large. I found a shellcode to execute execve(/bin/sh) at http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-827.php and replaced \x2f\x2f\x73\x68, which is for sh, with \x2f\x62\x61\x73, which is for bash. I turned off ASLR, and compiled final1.c with gcc with the options -m32, -zexecstack, and -fno-stack-protector. The following was a test payload to see if I could overwrite the return address:[image]
19 nops followed by my 23 byte shellcode and fours a's, making the payload 46 bytes.

When I run final1 with /tmp/input in gdb, I can see that I can overwrite the return address.
[image]
The highlighted addresses are the overflowed buffer. I can tell I've overwritten the return address because of the four 61's in the segmentation fault error.

This is where I've run into difficulties. Instead of having four a's overwrite the return address, I used an address somewhere in the middle of the nop sled in my payload: I chose the address `0xbffff1ea`. However, instead of opening bash, I see this when I run final1 with the payload:
[image]

The number in the segmentation fault isn't the last four bytes of the payload as in the first run, so I assume that means it jumped. I also noticed that the number that is shown, `0xbffff105`, is the address of one of the bytes in the shellcode, which I've higlighted in yellow.

I've hit a wall at this point. Does anyone know why I am having these troubles? Also, if my understanding of what I'm doing seems to be off, I encourage you to correct me.

Comment: try to choose other middle_of_nop_sled address, if it doesn't work i'll install 32bit vm :(, can u upload the binary ?

Comment: I'm using a vm of a 32 bit Arch Linux machine. Where do I find the binary?

Comment: meant the crackme binary.. nvm.. tried other addresses ?

Comment: I just tried several addresses in the nop sled, from addresses in the middle to addresses closer to each edge. I keep having the same problem, and the same address keeps showing up in the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash and sh are two different shells. Basically bash is sh, with more features and better syntax. Most commands work the same, but they are different.

Having said that, you should realize /bin/sh on most systems will be a symbolic link and will not invoke sh. In Ubuntu /bin/sh used to link to bash, typical behavior on Linux distributions, but now has changed to linking to another shell called dash.

So, in short, I think you don't need to change the hexdecimal part of the execve function.

Comment: I tried it with the original shellode (the one with sh) and I encountered the same problem. I'm using 32-bit Arch Linux; I don't know whether or not Arch behaves the same as other distros with respect to sh.

Answer (score 0):

Your shellcode has a bunch of instructions which change the stack.

```
   0:    31 c0                    xor    eax, eax
   2:    50                       push   eax
   3:    68 2f 62 61 73           push   0x7361622f
   8:    68 2f 62 69 6e           push   0x6e69622f
   d:    89 e3                    mov    ebx, esp
   f:    50                       push   eax
  10:    53                       push   ebx
  11:    89 e1                    mov    ecx, esp
  13:    b0 0b                    mov    al, 0xb
  15:    cd 80                    int    0x80
```

Your `esp` points after the end of the shellcode. After the first `push` , `esp` points to the last 4 bytes of your shellcode. As the shellcode continues execution subsequent pushes to the stack will actually overwrite some part of the shellcode. I suggest you add some code in the start of the shellcode so that your esp points a bit far from shellcode. `add esp,0x7f` does not contain any null byte and fits in 3 bytes "83c470"